# Book about friends in the woods that encounter a UFO (or something) and get powers and start turning on each other

Tags: story-identification, novel, powers

I remember reading this book in elementary school during the early 90's.  I don't remember why they are in the woods, but a group of friends either go camping, or break down.  They are probably in their late teens or 20's.  They encounter a UFO or meteor and start to get powers.  One of them starts to turn against the others and become evil.  This is about all I can remember. I would love to find this book again.  I'm guessing it was written in the late 80's or early 90's.

Comment: Hmm... a few quick searches didn't turn up anything promising, but parts of this sound very much like Christopher Pike, who was fond of writing teenagers encountering strange things like aliens (several of his books are loosely tied together with a narrative of humans being influenced by alien remnants/ancestry) and horror including people turning evil and groups turning on each other.

Comment: This sounds very much like the plot of the film "Chronicle"...but the film is from 2012, and doesn't appear to be (directly at least) derived from a book.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like Steven King's The Tommyknockers from 1987: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tommyknockers: "While maintaining a horror style, the novel is an excursion into the realm of science fiction for King, as the residents of the Maine town of Haven gradually fall under the influence of a mysterious object buried in the woods. "